# Silex - What's the fastest way to serialize a database resultset in JSON?

Tags: php, json, silex, dbal

At the moment I retrieve records from db using [DBAL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html)  and then I transform each row in a corresponding object. Each object is appended to an array and finally it's [converted to json with json() function](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#json).
Example code:

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
  public function getById(Request $request, Application $app, $id) {
      $this->app = $app;
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ...";
      $stmt = $app['db']->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute();
      $obj = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return $app->json($this->convert($obj));
    }


  public function convert($resultset) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($resultset as $key => $row) {
        $myObj = new MyObj();
        $myObj->setId($row['id']);
        // and so on
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Can this serialization method modified to be faster? Put the case I have to send a REST client **one hundred thousand objects**, is there [a sort of streming mode like for files](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#streaming) so I can avoid buffering all results in a temporary array?
Thanks

Comment: http://blog.salsify.com/engineering/json-streaming-parser-for-php

Comment: @castis: it seems it applies to reading a big json file.

Answer (score 2):

If your class properties map to the column names in the database, you could fetch the objects directly using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`. That will not give you any streaming but it will skip the whole conversion step:

```
public function getById(Request $request, Application $app, $id) {
  $this->app = $app;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ...";
  $stmt = $app['db']->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();

  // Generate an array of the required objects
  $arr = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "MyObj");

  // Encode the array
  return $app->json($arr);
}
```